# Working from Home in EU

Tags: employment, european-union, germany

Is there anything in EU (or German) law or directives to encourage or even mandate working from home, outside of a pandemic? Are there plans to do so?

Background: I plan to move to a neighbor EU country and would like to explore arguments for working from home full time. I am employed by the state of Bavaria, if that makes a difference.

Comment: There are many legal issues with working from home fulltime in another country (see [this overview](https://www.ihk.de/duesseldorf/aussenwirtschaft/rechtsfragen/homeoffice-und-mobiles-arbeiten-im-ausland-5238408) in German). It is extremely unlikely that a state agency will allow it. (Believe me, I work for a federal agency and we have had these discussions.)

Comment: However, there are political discussions and strategies regarding the contribution of working from home to mitigation of greenhouse gas emissions. That could lead to the directives you are hoping for.

Comment: *employed by the state of Bavaria* Beamter or Angestellter? Germany distinguishes between working from home and working mobile. When working from home, the employer has to make sure your workplace complies to certain standards.

Comment: @Bernhard Döbler Angestellter. Currently, we can work from home for up to 2 days per week.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, that was my impression, too. As climate change is introduced with law regarding pandemics, even that might lead to temporary measures only...